# mockery overload class missing methods

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, mockery

Need a bit of help using Mockery - I want to overload a class, which is created using `new HelperUtil()` in a method.

Using Mockery `overload` I can do this, but it is leaving me with an empty shell  class. Which I then appear to have to create all methods that are called. Is there a way to create a overloaded full mock, and then change just one method?

```
    $mock = \Mockery::mock('overload:'.HelperUtil::class);
    $mock->shouldReceive('content')->andReturnUsing(function() {
        return 'different content';
    });
```

thanks

edit: 
I think i want to do:

```
    $mock = \Mockery::mock('overload:'.HelperUtil::class)->shouldDeferMissing();
    $mock->shouldReceive('content')->andReturnUsing(function() {
        return 'different content';
    });
```

But that still dosnt work =(

Answer (score 3):

There is an [interesting discussion](https://github.com/padraic/mockery/issues/177) about it on GitHub

> `shouldIgnoreMissing` and `shouldDeferMissing` (and other such flags
>   present and future) do work, but not on the mock, but on the instance
>   mock.
>
> Sounds confusing, but it's because of internals.
>
> When you do a `m::mock('overload:Foo');` mockery goes and creates a new
>   class called `Foo` based on the `Mock.php` "template". And that template
>   has the `_mockery_ignoreMissing` flag set to false by default.
>
> Once the mock method gets to the end, it creates an overloaded `Foo`
>   object and returns it to us. The overloaded `Foo` class is also
>   available to instantiate new `Foo` objects.
>
> Calling `$m->shouldIgnoreMissing()` sets the ignore missing flag on the
>   object that was returned by the mock method.
>
> Calling `new Foo()` creates a new instance of the `Foo` object that has
>   the `Mock.php` templates default of false for `_mockery_ignoreMissing`.
>
> If you want the flag set to true on the new instance, you need to call
>   `shouldIgnoreMissing()` on that instance, and not on `$m`.

As I see, feature "[should ignore missing on instance mocks](https://github.com/padraic/mockery/issues/436)" has been completed, so the best you can do is

```
$mock = \Mockery::mock('overload:'.HelperUtil::class)->shouldIgnoreMissing();
```

I don't see `shouldDeferMissing` has been done yet for `overload`.

Of course, as a workaround, you might consider creating a mock and injecting it.